# Calculate number of decimal digits in BigInteger

Tags: java, class, math, biginteger

I'm trying to use `BigInteger` values along side `Math.Log10` method.

```
final BigInteger answerNo = fact;
final int digits = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(answerNo));
```

Unfortunately the compiler says *incompatible types*.

If I change the `int`s to `BigInteger`s it still doesn't like it.

Comment: I've changed the title of this question to make it comply with the information in the question and accepted answer. Obviously counting the digits is not as precise as performing an actual 10 based logarithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing a `log10` you can find the number of digits by simply doing:

```
int digits = answerNo.toString().length();
```

Comment: If that's the goal, then it would indeed be a lot simpler!

Comment: Might want to subtract 1 from that :)

Comment: That's irrelevant. You need neither subtract nor add one if you want to get the number of digits. @RayToal Only if you wanted to compute the floored log_10

Comment: This is great. So much simpler. Thanks a lot. Perfect answer.

Comment: @epsalon OH! Of course, the OP wanted one plus the log.  My miss.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't assign an `int` to a `BigInteger` - you could write: `final BigInteger answerNo = BigInteger.valueOf(fact);`
2. `Mat.log10` expects a `double`, not a `BigInteger`

If you don't mind a loss of precision, you could simply use doubles:

```
final int digits = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(fact));
```

If you care about precision, you will need to calculate the log manually.

Comment: Good idea, but it breaks when digits > 314, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger.toString()` can be inefficient in terms of memory if you only care for count of digits.

You can instead try converting `BigInteger` into a `BigDecimal` and use the `BigDecimal.precision()` to achieve the same. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930827/3844538) for details.